# Good algorithm for combining items from N lists into one with balanced distribution?

Tags: algorithm, list

Let's say I have the three following lists

A1
A2
A3

B1
B2

C1
C2
C3
C4
C5

I'd like to combine them into a single list, with the items from each list as evenly distributed as possible sorta like this:

C1
A1
C2
B1
C3
A2
C4
B2
A3
C5

I'm using .NET 3.5/C# but I'm looking more for how to approach it then specific code.

EDIT: I need to keep the order of elements from the original lists.

Comment: It looks to me that you don't simply want to combine them, you want them to be merged them together evenly like a zipper or cars politely merging on a highway. Am I correct?

Comment: Does this algorithm have a well-known name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Take a copy of the list with the most members. This will be the destination list.
2. Then take the list with the next largest number of members.
3. divide the destination list length by the smaller length to give a fractional value of greater than one.
4. For each item in the second list, maintain a float counter. Add the value calculated  in the previous step, and mathematically round it to the nearest integer (keep the original float counter intact). Insert it at this position in the destination list and increment the counter by 1 to account for it. Repeat for all list members in the second list.
5. Repeat steps 2-5 for all lists.

EDIT: This has the advantage of being O(n) as well, which is always nice :)

Comment: A variation on this would be to use Bresenham's line algorithm instead of the float counter in step 4. To inserting N objects into the existing list of M objects evenly is equivalent to enumerating the points of a rasterized line from <0,0> to <M,N>.

Comment: Well, it pretty boils down the the same thing... The overflow/rounding is the core of bresenhams.

Comment: @AndrewRollings can you please explain in detail or a `pseudocode` will be more than enough for me to understand?  
i am not able to understand your answer clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of 
Andrew Rollings' answer:

```cs
public List<String> equimix(List<List<String>> input) {

  // sort biggest list to smallest list
  Collections.sort(input, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
     public int compare(List<String> a1, List<String> a2) {
        return a2.size() - a1.size();
     }
  });

  List<String> output = input.get(0);

  for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++) {
     output = equimix(output, input.get(i));
  }

  return output;
}

public List<String> equimix(List<String> listA, List<String> listB) {

  if (listB.size() > listA.size()) {
     List<String> temp;
     temp = listB;
     listB = listA;
     listA = temp;
  }

  List<String> output = listA;

  double shiftCoeff = (double) listA.size() / listB.size();
  double floatCounter = shiftCoeff;

  for (String item : listB) {
     int insertionIndex = (int) Math.round(floatCounter);
     output.add(insertionIndex, item);
     floatCounter += (1+shiftCoeff);
  }

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, this answer is more of a train of thought than a concete solution.

OK, so you have a list of 3 items (A1, A2, A3), where you want A1 to be somewhere in the first 1/3 of the target list, A2 in the second 1/3 of the target list, and A3 in the third 1/3. Likewise you want B1 to be in the first 1/2, etc...

So you allocate your list of 10 as an array, then start with the list with the most items, in this case C. Calculate the spot where C1 should fall (1.5) Drop C1 in the closest spot, (in this case, either 1 or 2), then calculate where C2 should fall (3.5) and continue the process until there are no more Cs.

Then go with the list with the second-to-most number of items. In this case, A. Calculate where A1 goes (1.66), so try 2 first. If you already put C1 there, try 1. Do the same for A2 (4.66) and A3 (7.66). Finally, we do list B. B1 should go at 2.5, so try 2 or 3. If both are taken, try 1 and 4 and keep moving radially out until you find an empty spot. Do the same for B2.

You'll end up with something like this if you pick the lower number:

C1 A1 C2 A2 C3 B1 C4 A3 C5 B2

or this if you pick the upper number:

A1 C1 B1 C2 A2 C3 A3 C4 B2 C5

This seems to work pretty well for your sample lists, but I don't know how well it will scale to many lists with many items. Try it and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of a divide and conquer approach. Each iteration of which you split all the lists with elements > 1 in half and recurse. When you get to a point where all the lists except one are of one element you can randomly combine them, pop up a level and randomly combine the lists removed from that frame where the length was one... et cetera.

Something like the following is what I'm thinking:

```
- filter lists into three categories
    - lists of length 1
    - first half of the elements of lists with > 1 elements
    - second half of the elements of lists with > 1 elements
- recurse on the first and second half of the lists if they have > 1 element
    - combine results of above computation in order
- randomly combine the list of singletons into returned list
```

Comment: Would this be any better than Will's answer?

Answer (score 1):

- Make a hash table of lists.
- For each list, store the nth element in the list under the key `(/ n (+ (length list) 1))`
- Optionally, shuffle the lists under each key in the hash table, or sort them in some way
- Concatenate the lists in the hash by sorted key

Answer (score 0):

You could simply combine the three lists into a single list and then UNSORT that list.  An unsorted list should achieve your requirement of 'evenly-distributed' without too much effort.

Here's an implementation of unsort: http://www.vanheusden.com/unsort/.

Comment: Sounds like it randomizes the elements. While it would probably work most of the time, some of the time you'd get a rather unbalanced distribution.

Comment: yeah I noticed that after I posted my solution.

Answer (score -1):

A quick suggestion, in python-ish pseudocode:

```
merge = list()
lists = list(list_a, list_b, list_c)
lists.sort_by(length, descending)

while lists is not empty:
    l = lists.remove_first()
    merge.append(l.remove_first())
    if l is not empty:
        next = lists.remove_first()
        lists.append(l)
        lists.sort_by(length, descending)
        lists.prepend(next)
```

This should distribute elements from shorter lists more evenly than the other suggestions here.

Comment: This psuedocode does not work in all cases. I implemented it and tried using two lists of sizes 2 and 6. There was an IndexError from trying to remove an element from an empty list.