# A practical example of evenly distributing n lists into a single list

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I had previously asked about how to evenly distribute the items in n lists into a single list and was referred to this question: [Good algorithm for combining items from N lists into one with balanced distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344860/good-algorithm-for-combining-items-from-n-lists-into-one-with-balanced-distribut).

I made a practical example of my solution for this in VBA for Excel, since my application for this was resorting my Spotify lists which can be easily pasted into Excel for manipulation. Assumptions are that you have a headerless worksheet (wsSource) of songs with columns A, B, C representing Artist, Song, SpotifyURI respectively, a "Totals" worksheet (wsTotals) containing the sum of songs for each Artist from wsSource sorted in descending order, and a "Destination" worksheet where the new list will be created. Could I get some suggestions to improve this? I was going to get rid of the totals worksheet and have this portion done in code, but I have to go and I wanted to go ahead and put this out there. Thanks!

```
Sub WeaveSort()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTotals As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim iLast As Integer
Dim iDest As Integer
Dim iSource As Integer
Dim iOldRow As Integer
Dim iNewRow As Integer
Dim dDiff As Double
Dim dDiffSum As Double

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTotals = wb.Worksheets("Totals")
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Source")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Dest")
    iLast = wsTotals.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

    For i = 2 To iLast
        iSource = wsTotals.Range("B" & i).Value
        iDest = wsDest.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row

        If i = 2 Then
            wsDest.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2 = wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Value2
            wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
            GoTo NextI
        End If

        dDiff = iDest / iSource
        dDiffSum = 0
        iNewRow = 0

        For iOldRow = 1 To iSource
            dDiff = iDest / iSource
            dDiffSum = dDiffSum + dDiff
            iNewRow = Round(dDiffSum, 0)
            wsSource.Rows(iOldRow).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(iNewRow).Insert xlShiftDown
            iDest = iDest + 1
        Next iOldRow

        wsSource.Range("A1:C" & iSource).Delete (xlShiftUp)
NextI:
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing? Does it work?

Comment: It works for me. I just wanted to see if someone had a better idea for solving the problem of evenly distributing n lists into a single list in Excel.

Comment: Consider cross posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ This is exactly the kind of questions we like to see.

Comment: Yes! I thought there must be something like that in the StackExchange, but I didn't see it on a quick glance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  I would take an object oritentated approach.  Also I didn;t think it was clear what the logic was so here is my answer. Two classes and one normal module.  Save these separately with the filenames ListManager.cls, List.cls, tstListManager.bas

So the ListManager.cls is this

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ListManager"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private mdic As Object

Public Sub Initialise(ByVal vLists As Variant)

    Set mdic = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    Dim vListLoop As Variant
    For Each vListLoop In vLists
        Dim oList As List
        Set oList = New List
        oList.Initialise vListLoop, ""
        mdic.Add mdic.Count, oList
    Next

End Sub

Public Function WeaveSort() As Variant

    Dim dicReturn As Object
    Set dicReturn = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim oNextList As List
    Set oNextList = Me.WhichListHasLeastProgress
    While oNextList.PercentageDone <= 1
        Dim vListItem As Variant
        vListItem = oNextList.GetListItem
        dicReturn.Add dicReturn.Count, vListItem
        oNextList.MoveNext

        Set oNextList = Me.WhichListHasLeastProgress
    Wend

    Dim vItems As Variant
    vItems = dicReturn.Items


    'I don't like this bit
    ReDim vRet(1 To dicReturn.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 0 To dicReturn.Count - 1
        vRet(lLoop + 1, 1) = vItems(lLoop)
    Next lLoop

    WeaveSort = vRet

End Function


Public Function WhichListHasLeastProgress() As List
    Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
    Dim oListLoop As List
    Dim oLeastProgress As List

    For Each vKeyLoop In mdic.keys

        Set oListLoop = mdic.Item(vKeyLoop)

        If oLeastProgress Is Nothing Then
            'nothing to compare yet
            Set oLeastProgress = oListLoop
        Else
            If oListLoop.PercentageDone < oLeastProgress.PercentageDone Then
                'definitely take this new candidate
                Set oLeastProgress = oListLoop
            ElseIf oListLoop.PercentageDone = oLeastProgress.PercentageDone And oListLoop.Size > oListLoop.Size Then
                'close thing, both showing equal progress but we should give it to the one with the bigger "queue"
                Set oLeastProgress = oListLoop
            Else
                'no swap
            End If
        End If

    Next

    'return the answer
    Set WhichListHasLeastProgress = oLeastProgress

End Function
```

and the List.cls file is

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "List"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private mvList As Variant
Private mlCount As Long
Private mlCursor As Long
Private mvName As Variant

Public Function Initialise(ByRef vList As Variant, ByVal vName As Variant)

    Debug.Assert TypeName(vList(1, 1)) <> "" ' this will break unless you specify a 2d array
    Debug.Assert LBound(vList, 1) = 1 ' this ensure you got it from a sheet

    mvList = vList
    mlCount = UBound(mvList)
    mlCursor = 1
    mvName = vName
End Function

Public Function GetListItem()
    GetListItem = mvList(mlCursor, 1)
End Function


Public Function Name() As Variant
    Name = mvName
End Function

Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean
    mlCursor = mlCursor + 1
    MoveNext = (mlCursor < mlCount)
End Function

Public Function Size() As Long
    Size = mlCount
End Function

Public Function PercentageDone() As Double
    PercentageDone = mlCursor / mlCount
End Function
```

The last file is this tstListManager.bas

```
Attribute VB_Name = "tstListManager"
Option Explicit


Sub test()
    Dim oListMan As ListManager
    Set oListMan = New ListManager

    Dim vLists As Variant
    vLists = VBA.Array(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Range("A1:A3").Value2, _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Range("B1:B2").Value2, _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Range("C1:C5").Value2)

    oListMan.Initialise vLists

    Dim vSorted As Variant
    vSorted = oListMan.WeaveSort

    Dim lTotal As Long


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dest").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vSorted, 1)).Value2 = vSorted
End Sub
```

Finally, the test data was in A1:A3  B1:B2   C1:C5

You should note I have abstracted away any Excel reading/writing logic and the pure weavesort logic is not cluttered.

Feel free to reject outright.  Object orientation can be quite controversial and we think differently.  :)