# Algorithm for evenly spacing list items (playlist songs) along several categories (id3 tags)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, sorting, playlist

I am having trouble designing an algorithm to assist in the creation of an mp3 playlist, although an algorithm for the more general case of evenly spacing items in a list could be adapted for my use.

The general case is that I would like to reorder items in a list to maximize their diversity along several axes.

My specific use-case is that I want to dump a bunch of songs into a collection, then run my algorithm over the collection to generate an ordered playlist. I would like the order to follow this set of criteria:

1. maximize the distance between instances of the same artist
2. maximize the distance between instances of the same genre
3. maximize the distance between instances of category X
4. etc for N categories

Obviously we could not guarantee to optimize ALL categories equally, so the first category would be weighted most important, second weighted less, etc. I definitely want to satisfy the first two criteria, but making the algorithm extensible to satisfy N would be fantastic.  Maximizing randomness (shuffle) is not a priority. I just want to diversify the listening experience no matter where I come in on the playlist.

This seems close to the problem described and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344860/good-algorithm-for-combining-items-from-n-lists-into-one-with-balanced-distribut), but I can't wrap my head around how to apply this when all of the items are in the same list with multiple dimensions, rather than separate lists of differing sizes.

This seems like a problem that would have been solved many times by now but I am not able to find any examples of it.

Comment: I am seeing great answers explaining why this problem will be difficult to solve, but just in case some genius has an elegant solution we haven't thought of, I'd like to throw another constraint on the problem: the "maximal distance" should take into account the fact that the playlist may be on repeat.  This means that simply putting two songs by the same artist at opposite ends of the playlist will fail since they will be "next to" each other when the list repeats.

Comment: I updated my answer with a response to your comment.

Comment: I think you will get your answer much faster if you consider leaving some individual feedback to each answer describing why it doesn't solve your problem. Considering how your problem is described, I see three answers (mine, Edward Doolittle's and BraveNewCurrency's) which should be good solutions.

Comment: Sorry I have not chosen a best solution yet.  This is a personal project that I only have time for occasionally so it will be a while before I can implement and compare all the suggestions.Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea: you create a graph, where songs are vertices, and paths represent their diversity.

For example we have five songs:

1. "A", country, authored by John Doe
2. "B", country, authored by Jane Dean
3. "C", techno, authored by Stan Chang
4. "D", techno, authored by John Doe
5. "E", country, authored by John Doe

We assign weight 2 to artist and 1 to genre, and use multiplicative inverse as path's value. Some of the path will look like this:

`A-B`: `2*1 + 1*0 = 2` => value of the path is 1/2 = `0.5`

`A-C`: `2*1 + 1*1 = 3` => value of the path is 1/3 = `0.33`

`A-D`: `2*0 + 1*1 = 1` => value of the path is 1/1 = `1`

`A-E`: `2*0 + 1*0 = 0` => value of the path is 1/0 = `MAX_DOUBLE`

You can have as many categories as you want, weighted as you wish.

Once you have calculated all paths between all songs, all you have to do is use some heuristic algorithm for [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

EDIT:

> I'd like to throw another constraint on the problem: the "maximal distance" should take into account the fact that the playlist may be on repeat. This means that simply putting two songs by the same artist at opposite ends of the playlist will fail since they will be "next to" each other when the list repeats.

Part of Travelling Salesman Problem is that in the end you return to your origin point, so you will have the same song at both ends of your playlist, and both paths (from song and to song) will be calculated with the best efficiency allowed by used heuristics. So all you have to do is remove last entry from your result (because it's the same as the first one) and you can safely repeat without breaking your requirements.

Comment: That ensures that songs 1 and 2 are as different as possible, and similarly for songs 2 and 3, but songs 1 and 3 could be quite similar, whereas in an optimal solution, songs similar to song 1 might be much further along in the list.

Comment: It's just a simple example to illustrate my point. You can have as many categories as you want and weight them however you wish. Besides, using author an genre to tell whether songs are different was OP's idea. For optimal solution you can calculate Fourier transform for each song and compare their spectrum (or compare some other mathematical properties of each song).

Comment: I was able to put a test together using a TSP Heuristic algorithm, and as Edward Doolittle said, I found clusters of paired artists in a row alternating ArtistA, ArtistB, ArtistA, ArtistB, etc. I don't believe weighting will have an effect on this behavior since the algorithm only looks at neighbors, not neighbors of neighbors.  I will look at some of the other suggestions and see if implementing them is within my skillset.

Comment: You can make an easy modification to remove clusters of alternating artists by remembering a list of last N artist. If inspected song's artist is on the list, add X to path's weight. Similar approach can be applied to other categories, with the same or different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This should be much faster than brute-force:

1. Order all the songs randomly.
2. Compute the weights for each song slot (i.e. how close is it to the same artist/genre/etc.).   It will be a number from 1-N indicating how may songs away it is from a match. Lower is worse.
3. Take the song with the lowest weight, and swap that song with a random other song.
4. Re-compute the weights of the swapped songs. If either got worse, reverse the swap and go back to 3.
5. For debugging, print the "lowest weight" and overall average weight. (debugging)
6. Go to 2

You won't find the optimal this way, but it should give mediocre results pretty fast, and eventually improve.

Step 2 can be made fast this way: (pseudo code in Ruby)

```
# Find the closest match to a song in slot_number
def closest_match(slot_number)
  # Note: MAX can be less than N. Maybe nobody cares about songs more than 20 steps away.
  (1..MAX).each |step|
    return step if matches?(slot_number+step, slot_number) or matches?(slot_number-step, slot_number)
  end
  return MAX
end

# Given 2 slots, do the songs there match?
# Handles out-of-bounds
def matches?(x,y)
  return false if y > N or y < 1
  return false if x > N or x < 1
  s1 = song_at(x)
  s2 = song_at(y)
  return true if s1.artist == s2.artist or s1.genre == s2.genere
  return false
end
```

You also don't have to re-compute the whole array: If you cache the weights, you only need to recompute songs that have weight >=X if they are X steps away from a swapped song. Example:

```
|  Song1   |  Song2   |   Song3  |  Song4   |  Song5  |
| Weight=3 | Weight=1 | Weight=5 | Weight=3 | Weight=2|
```

If you are swapping Song 2, you don't have to re-compute song 5: It's 3 steps away from Song 3, but it's weight was 2, so it won't "see" Song 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably NP-hard. To get a sense of it, here's a reduction to CLIQUE (an NP-hard problem). That doesn't prove that your problem is NP-hard, but at least gives an idea that there is a connection between the two problems. (To show definitively that your problem is NP-hard, you need a reduction in the other direction: show that CLIQUE can be reduced to your problem. I feel that it is possible, but getting the details right is fussy.)

Suppose you have n=6 songs, A, B, C, D, E, and F. Lay them out in a chart like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
A A A A A A
B B B B B B
C C C C C C
D D D D D D
E E E E E E
F F F F F F
```

Connect each item in column 1 with an edge to every other item in every other column, except for items in the same row. So A in column 1 is connected to B, C, D, E, F in column 2, B, C, D, E, F in column 3, and so on. There are n^2 = 36 nodes in the graph and `n*(n-1)^2 + n*(n-1)*(n-2) + n*(n-1)*(n-3) + ... = n*(n-1)*n*(n-1)/2 = O(n^4)` edges in the graph.

A playlist is a maximum clique in this graph, in other words a selection which is mutually consistent (no song is played twice). So far, not so hard: it's possible to find many maximum cliques very quickly (just permutations of the songs).

Now we add information about the similarity of the songs as edge weights. Two songs that are similar and close get a low edge weight. Two songs that are similar and far apart get a higher edge weight. Now the problem is to find a maximum clique with maximum total edge weight, in other words the NP-hard problem CLIQUE.

There are some algorithms for attacking CLIQUE, but of course they're exponential in time. The best you're going to be able to do in a reasonable amount of time is either to run one of those algorithms and take the best result it can generate in that time, or to randomly generate permutations for a given amount of time and pick the one with the highest score. You might be able to get better results for natural data using something like simulated annealing to solve the optimization problem, but CLIQUE is "hard to approximate" so I have the feeling you won't get  much better results that way than by randomly generating proposals and picking the highest scoring.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force algorithm for that is easy.

```
maxDistance = 0
foreach ordering
  distance = 0
  foreach category
    for i=1 to numsongs
      for j=i+1 to numsongs
        if song i and song j in this ordering have same value for this category
          distance = distance + (j-i)*weight_for_this_category
        endif
      endfor
    endfor
  endfor
  if ( distance > maxDistance )
    maxDistance = distance
    mark ordering as best one so far
  endif
endfor
```

But that algorithm has worse than exponential complexity with the number of songs so it will take unmanageable ammounts of time pretty fast. The hard part comes in doing it in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about a "spring" approach.  If new items are added to the end of the list, they squish the similar items forward.

If I add pink Floyd to the list, then all other Floyd songs get squished to make space.

I would implement the least common dimensions before the most common dimensions, to ensure the more common dimensions are better managed.

```
For tags in song ordered by count tags in list asc
   Evenly space earlier songs with knowledge new song being added
Add song
```