# Merging a 2D array with sorted rows into a big 1D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a 2d array which each row is sorted from left to right, from the smallest to the biggest, I want to sort the entire array into a 1D array from the smallest to the biggest.

the number of rows is N and the number of columns is M.
the complexity I need for it is M*N*log(N)

What I had in mind to do, is do some kind of a merge sort on the 2d array and each time send 2 rows for the function and there is the point I got stuck.

the signature I'm given for the function is

```
void sort_rect(int a[N][M], int b[])
```

I'm promised the the 1d array of b has enough space for all the element of the 2d array.#C!!!

Comment: Merge sorting indeed sounds like what you need, merging the rows into the destination array. Can you please elaborate on your problem? What part are you getting stuck on? Merge sort in general? Something else?

Comment: I wrote the merge function, the copy function, I'm stuck on one main thing, first is how can I send each time 2 rows and then store the 1d array of two row some where? secondly I need the complecity run to be MN(log(N)) and not MNlog(NM)

Comment: Input (N = 3 ;M = 4):
1 5 8 10
3 4 5 6
2 3 3 9

Output:
1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 8 9 10

Comment: Is each row(array) in your 2-d array sorted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good algorithm for combining items from N lists into one with balanced distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344860/good-algorithm-for-combining-items-from-n-lists-into-one-with-balanced-distribut)

Comment: Two of the answers below suggest implementing an N way merge, which would be the conventional way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard approach (of merging the sorted arrays and then sorting) will give you `O(NMLog(NM))`.If you want an efficient approach then you should use min Heap data structure.You might want to read about heap data structure.

1. Create an output array of size `N*M`.This will hold the output sorted array.
2. Create a min heap of size `N`.Insert first element of every sorted array.
3. Remove the top element(minimum) from heap and put it in the output array.Replace this removed element with the next element from the same array of which this removed element was part.Repeat this until all elements are accounted for.

Complexity will be `O(NMLog(N))`.

Comment: Note - as the end of each row is reached, the number of rows and the size of the min heap decreases by 1, until there is just a portion of one row remaining, where the remainder of that row is copied to complete the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the elements in `a[M][N]` reside in sequential memory, you can treat that memory as flat. So you sort in place like this:

```
int *c = (int *)a;
```

and sort `c`, given that the size of the array is `M*N`.

Or you can copy it to `b`, by defining `b` like this:

```
int b[sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(a));
```

and now sort `b`.

Comment: The total number of elements is `MN`, and the OP states he wants a sorting algorithm with complexity `MN log(N)` (not `MN log(MN)`). I don't believe simply using a common sorting algorithm to the flat `MN` array will yield such `MN log(N)` asymptotic performance. I would guess this needs some problem-specific sorter (e.g. a problem-specific merge sort) making use of the fact that the each of the `N` sub-arrays of length `M` are already sorted.

Comment: I also think something like that, but I cant get that one into code :(

Answer (score 0):

Think of a merge sort, but applied to N arrays instead of 2. For each row you could keep an index of currently considered element. Now we need something to compare all the N values (instead of just 2). What you could do is use a heap (priority_queue) with an element structure like this:

```
struct Element {
   int Value;
   int Row; //tells you which row in the 2d array the value comes from
}
```

The algorithm would be as follows:

1. You add all the values from the column 0 to the priority
   queue
2. Declare an array which will keep your currently considered index for each row. Initialize it to zeros.
3. In a loop (until you run out of elements)

   - check the element on the top of the queue (`element = queue.top()`)
   - add `element.Value` to the 1d array
   - increment currently considered index for `element.Row`
   - remove the element from the top of the priority queue (`queue.pop()`)

The resulting 1d array is sorted and the complexity is O(MNlog(N)). This is because you considered M*N elements and for each element adding/removing it from the priority_queue took log(N) time, because at any given moment the heap keeps no more than N elements.

I think that treating the 2d array as 1d and sorting would result in MNlog(MN) complexity which is a bit worse.

Comment: What about a class? This might as well be just a class with public fields.

Comment: This would be a N way merge, not a merge sort.